# How to export a GPG private key and public key to a file

Tags: gpg, pgp, openpgp

I have generated keys using GPG, by executing the following command

```
gpg --gen-key
```

Now I need to export the key pair to a file;
i.e., private and public keys to `private.pgp` and `public.pgp`, respectively. 
How do I do it?

Comment: P.S. in GPG 2 please use `gpg --full-generate-key` to have a full interface for generating keys

Answer (score 400, accepted):

**Export Public Key**

This command will export an ascii armored version of the public key:

`gpg --output public.pgp --armor --export username@email`

**Export Secret Key**

This command will export an ascii armored version of the secret key:

`gpg --output private.pgp --armor --export-secret-key username@email`

---

**Security Concerns, Backup, and Storage**

A PGP public key contains information about one's email address.  This is generally acceptable since the public key is used to encrypt email to your address.  However, in some cases, this is undesirable.

For most use cases, **the secret key** need not be exported and **should not be distributed**.  If the purpose is to create a backup key, you should use the backup option:

`gpg --output backupkeys.pgp --armor --export-secret-keys --export-options export-backup user@email`

This will export all necessary information to restore the secrets keys including the trust database information.  Make sure you store any backup secret keys off the computing platform and in a secure physical location.

If this key is important to you, I recommend printing out the key on paper using [paperkey](https://www.jabberwocky.com/software/paperkey/).  And placing the paper key in a fireproof/waterproof safe.

**Public Key Servers**

In general, it's not advisable to post personal public keys to key servers.  There is no method of removing a key once it's posted and there is no method of ensuring that the key on the server was placed there by the supposed owner of the key.

It is much better to place your public key on a website that you own or control.  Some people recommend [keybase.io](https://keybase.io/) for distribution.  However, that method tracks participation in various social and technical communities which may not be desirable for some use cases.

For the technically adept, I personally recommend trying out the [webkey](https://www.gnupg.org/blog/20160830-web-key-service.html) domain level key discovery service.

Comment: Is the exported key (second command) encrypted or do I need to encrypt it by myself before storing it on a.g. a USB drive?

Comment: @Julian ... The exported secret key has the same protection as the secret key that was exported.  If there was a passphrase, the passphrase is required to import the secret key.

Comment: I made a backup using the above method, but foolishly forgot to test it. Unless I'm missing something, I can't seem to recover my public key from the backup method specified (`--export-options export-backup`, etc). Am I missing something, or did I misunderstand the kind of backup it was making?

Comment: The documentation knows `--export-secret-keys`, but not `--export-secret-key`.

Comment: @OMGtechy How did you try to recover the key(s)? I could restore public keys by `gpg --import-options restore --import backupkeys.pgp`, but that does not restore secret keys, only the public ones, if backupkeys.pgp was created by `gpg --output backupkeys.pgp --armor --export --export-options export-backup`. In that `--armor` is not necessary and `export-backup` could be replaced by `backup`.

Comment: Note that Keybase has since been bought by Zoom, who have very close ties to China.

Comment: Does the backup option also export subkeys?

Comment: how do i get this thing on my iphone from linux?

Comment: @jarno On my GPG 2 both `--export-secret-key` and `--export-secret-keys` work

Comment: I have tried `gpg --output backupkeys.pgp --armor --export-secret-keys --export-options export-backup` but only the private key is exported

Comment: What do keyserver operators do when there's a GDPR Right-to-be-Forgotten request?

Comment: For those looking at how to import the exported backup file, this worked for me: `gpg --import-options restore --import ./backupkeys.pgp`

Comment: I was able to restore from `private.pgp` using `gpg --import ./private.gpg`, as shown in another answer. If someone reading this is able to, I suggest editing the answer to include this.

Comment: Does the secret key also include the public key?

Comment: I am still facing an issue , how can I pass , passphrase to `gpg --export-secret-keys > ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg`

Comment: Why does `gpg` need to know the key's passphrase in order to export an encrypted secret key?

Comment: when i add `gpg --export-secret-key` command to my bash script, it seems like it's not supported... is there an alternative way of exporting private key in bash?

Comment: What if I have completely different keys (not just subkeys) with the same email address?

Answer (score 45):

- List the keys you have:
  `gpg --list-secret-keys`
- Export the key:
  `gpg -o ~/my-key.asc --export-secret-key name`
- Copy it on another machine;
- Import the key:
  `gpg --import my-key.asc`

Comment: Note that `.asc` stands for ASCII, but the output of  `gpg --list-secret-keys` is binary.

Comment: Actually, .asc is for `ASCII armored` and the output is enciphered text.  You can safely cat it and see for yourself.  Also, like most linux files, the file extension is also arbitrary, doesn't technically have to be asc. @WeihangJian

Comment: It would be a good idea to remove the key file after it is imported and tests successfully.  If the file is sitting there it could be used maliciously.

Comment: simply use -a option will export it in ASCII format, gpg -a --export-secret-keys name

Answer (score 17):

To `export` SOMEKEYID public key to an `output` file:

```
gpg --output public.pgp --export SOMEKEYID
```

When working with secret keys it's generally preferable not to write them to files and, instead, use SSH to copy them directly between machines using only `gpg` and a pipe:

```
gpg --export-secret-key SOMEKEYID | ssh othermachine gpg --import
```

If you must, however, output your secret key to a file please make sure it's encrypted. Here's how to accomplish that using AES encryption using the [Dark Otter approach](https://vhs.codeberg.page/post/moving-gpg-keys-privately/):

```
gpg --output public.gpg --export SOMEKEYID && \
gpg --output - --export-secret-key SOMEKEYID |\
    cat public.gpg - |\
    gpg --armor --output keys.asc --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256
```

The last approach is ideal if you want to create a physical back-up of your public and private keys to safeguard against a disk failure when no other way exists to regain access to your keys.

**Note:** If you only have a copy of your private key but not your public key it is possible to recovery your public key by reimporting the private key, trusting it, and then re-exporting.

See [Moving GPG Keys Privately](https://vhs.codeberg.page/post/moving-gpg-keys-privately/) for additional considerations.

Comment: Gave the Dark Otter approach a try but it fails with the follow error **gpg: cancelled by user
gpg: error creating passphrase: Operation cancelled
gpg: symmetric encryption of `[stdin]' failed: Operation cancelled**

Comment: I was able to get the Dark Otter Approach to work with GPG 1.4.21 but not GPG 2.0.22. Using 2.0.22 never prompts me to enter a passphrase.

Answer (score 4):

"GnuPG (aka PGP/GPG)" 
[More information](https://nsrc.org/workshops/2014/btnog/raw-attachment/wiki/Track3Agenda/2-1-1.pgp-lab.html)

Generate key:
`gpg --gen-key`

View all keys:
`gpg --list-keys`

Export public key:

```
gpg --export -a --output [path-to-public-key].asc [email-address]
```

Export secret key:

```
gpg -a --export-secret-keys > [path-to-secret-key].asc
```